# Firebase nested parsing Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have following Firebase query for parsing into my tableView

```
{
  "-LC8fVE90ovEFRQAhhdv" : {
    "description" : "Bu grupta arkadaşlar takılsınlar",
    "members" : [ "VSVmIF4o0ie2QMIcXdTDTcC8Hq93", "hJgM5tYU45VmjaMTzYAG4Yo3RyD2", "YrLEyhWf9KOIwoK2YN7HrzxpwMc2" ],
    "title" : "Takılmaca"
  },
  "-LC8wUR-11bX5FnjQ6Mk" : {
    "description" : "Hello",
    "members" : [ "VSVmIF4o0ie2QMIcXdTDTcC8Hq93", "hJgM5tYU45VmjaMTzYAG4Yo3RyD2", "nkwPkD2FeDZZFDnLunTe3D2EuQr2", "YrLEyhWf9KOIwoK2YN7HrzxpwMc2" ],
    "messages" : {
      "-LC9Pj9krCB4kZnXtXc8" : {
        "content" : "Its me",
        "senderId" : "YrLEyhWf9KOIwoK2YN7HrzxpwMc2"
      },"-LC9Pj9krCB4kasfXtXc8" : {
        "content" : "Who are you",
        "senderId" : "YrLEyhWf9KOIwoK2YN7HrzxpwMc2"
      }
}
```

I am trying to get content and senderId with following code

```
var groupMessages = [Message]()
REF_GROUPS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (groups) in
    guard let groups = groups.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }

    for group in groups {
        let groupss = group.value as? NSDictionary

        if let messages = groupss!["messages"] as? [String: Any] {

        }
    }            
    handler(groupMessages)
}
```

However, I could not reach content because of messages object is created by random identifiers (like LC9Pj9krCB4kZnXtXc8) how can I get that content and senderId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing don't ever use `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` in `Swift` it makes the things complex. Secondly just check `snapshot.exists()` instead of putting a `guard` for `allObjects`.

`for group in groups` should be replace by `for child in snapshot.children` and the `child` will be a `DataSnapshot` itself. See below code:

```
REF_GROUPS.observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in
     if snapshot.exists() {
         var allMessages: Array<Dictionary<String, String>> = []
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let childSnapshot = child as! DataSnapshot
                guard let dictValue = childSnapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, Any>, let messages = dictValue["messages"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> else {continue}
                if let array = Array(messages.values) as? Array<Dictionary<String, String>> {
                    allMessages.append(contentsOf: array)
                }
            }

            /// All messages into single array
            print(allMessages)

            /// All senderIds
            let senderIds = allMessages.map({$0["senderId"]!})
            print(senderIds)

            /// Unique senderIds
            let uniqueSenderIds = Array(Set(senderIds))
            print(uniqueSenderIds)

            /// Grouping the senderId with messages
            var finalDict: Dictionary<String, [String]> = [:]
            for data in allMessages {
                guard let senderId = data["senderId"], let content = data["content"] else {continue}
                if var oldValue = finalDict[senderId] {
                    oldValue.append(content)
                }
                else {
                    finalDict[senderId] = [content]
                }
            }
            print(finalDict)

            /// Inbuilt Dictionary grouping function
            let dictionary = Dictionary(grouping: allMessages, by: {$0["senderId"]!})
            print(dictionary)
}
```

**Output: allMessages**

```
[["content": "Its me", "senderId": "YrLEyhWf9KOIwoK2YN7HrzxpwMc2"],["content": "Who are you", "senderId": "YrLEyhWf9KOIwoK2YN7HrzxpwMc2"]]
```

**Output: senderIds**

```
["YrLEyhWf9KOIwoK2YN7HrzxpwMc2", "YrLEyhWf9KOIwoK2YN7HrzxpwMc2"]
```

**Output: uniqueSenderIds**

```
["YrLEyhWf9KOIwoK2YN7HrzxpwMc2"]
```

**Output: finalDict**

```
["YrLEyhWf9KOIwoK2YN7HrzxpwMc2": ["Its me", "Who are you"]]
```

**Output: finalDict**

```
["YrLEyhWf9KOIwoK2YN7HrzxpwMc2": [["content": "Its me", "senderId": "YrLEyhWf9KOIwoK2YN7HrzxpwMc2"], ["content": "Who are you", "senderId": "YrLEyhWf9KOIwoK2YN7HrzxpwMc2"]]]
```

I'm not sure why're you fetching all groups's content but I would like to suggest to get the data by `Groups -> GroupId -> messages` ref and put a listener for this ref so that app can be notify whenever new message will be received.

Comment: Thank you it is working like a charm. Actually I need to get all messages that is sent by specific user that is why I am iterating through all groups but I keep in mind your suggest too. Lastly how can I fetch senderId from that array?

Comment: @AtalayAsa I have edited the answer. If you need for all groups please make a global variable and append the `array` into that object.

Comment: It gave me an error like Type 'Any' has no subscript members in the mapping function.

Comment: Where ? Is `let array = Array(messages.values)` the array you're using?

Comment: Yes it is the array `let array = Array(messages.values)` but the error is occurring in the `array.map({$0["senderId"]!})` line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170857/discussion-between-thetiger-and-atalay-asa).